# React native - reload do nothing

Tags: android, react-native

I just started with React Native. I have my smartphone connected and after `react-native run-android` I can see "Hello World" on the screen. But when I change "Hello World" to something else, save the file, and then tap on the reload command on my device (after shaking phone), I can't see any changes. I need to `react-native run-android` again to see new things. I am working on Windows 10. Also build takes a lot of time. I have read similar things, but didn't find any reasonable solution. Can anyone help?

**Also:** Sometimes when I tap `Reload` then I need to press enter in packager server terminal, to reload view, but changes don't appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and found several solutions. The following is working for me:

**To enable life reloading with the >0.29 react-native-versions**

> 1. go to file: `yourProjectFolder//node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/server.js`
>
>    - Commend the line (62): process.exit(11) -> //process.exit(11)

*About Point 2: I am not sure since when the solution of 2.1. is needed but i think ~ react-native v.33. Please correct this if someone knows exactly. For you just look if you find the index.js at the 2. or 2.1. path.*

> - 2.1 (**Older Path of React-Native FileWatcher index.js**) Go to file: `yourProjectFolder//node_modules/react-native/node_modules\node-haste\lib\FileWatcher\index.js"`
> - 2.2 (**Newer Path of React-Native FileWatcher index.js**) Go to file:
>     `yourProjectFolder\node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src\node-haste\FileWatcher\index.js`

**STEP 1 for 2.1 + 2.2:**

- `Increase` at the top of the `index.js` file: `MAX_WAIT_TIME=120000` > `MAX_WAIT_TIME=360000`
- Change `function (_createWatcher)` to:

**STEP 2 for 2.1 (Older Path of index.js)**

```
key: '_createWatcher',
    value: function _createWatcher(rootConfig) {
        var watcher = new WatcherClass(rootConfig.dir, {
            glob: rootConfig.globs,
            dot: false
        });

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        const rejectTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            reject(new Error([
                'Watcher took too long to load',
                'Try running `watchman version` from your terminal',
                'https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html',
                ].join('\n')));
        }, MAX_WAIT_TIME);

        watcher.once('ready', function () {
          clearTimeout(rejectTimeout);
          resolve(watcher);
        });
    });
}
```

**STEP 2 for 2.2 (Newer Path of index.js)**

```
_createWatcher(rootConfig) {
    var watcher = new WatcherClass(rootConfig.dir, {
        glob: rootConfig.globs,
        dot: false
      });

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        const rejectTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
          reject(new Error([
            'Watcher took too long to load',
            'Try running `watchman version` from your terminal',
            'https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html',
          ].join('\n')));
        }, MAX_WAIT_TIME);

        watcher.once('ready', function () {
          clearTimeout(rejectTimeout);
          resolve(watcher);
        });
    });
}
```

*This solution worked for me. Hope I could help you and correct me if I am wrong.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you wrote in 2.1, but unfortunatelly in `myProjectFolder/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/server.js` I didn't find a line with `process.exit(1)`. I am using `react-native version 0.35.0`

Comment: On Tuesday i am back at work and I can have a look on it.

Comment: You are very kind. Thank you for initiative. I gonna try to overcome this issue by my own till this time. If I will find a solution I will share it here.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer. I looked inside my `server.js` and i find the `process.exit(11)`. I am also using `react-native 0.35.0`. The commended line is at line `67` and at the `process.on` call. Hope this can help you. BR Jonathan

Comment: Hi. Thank you for effort. I was looking literally for `process.exit(1)` and I didn't find it, but I found `process.exit(11)` and with that commented out reload is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey, sorry i will correct my answer. :) I am glad i could help you. BR